# How to stop apps from doubling overscan?

Tags: adb, touchscreen, broken-screen

For some reason a chunk of the digitizer broke on the bottom of my phone. I tried to use `adb shell wm overscan 0,54,0,324` to resize my screen smaller until I can get a new phone, but it's giving bad results.

It seems like the overscan is working normally at first, but then some of my apps, including Google's launcher, Nova Launcher, Gmail(except when composing), and the Play Store, are then shrinking in addition to the whole screen shrinking, leading everything to be half the size I want. I could just set the overscan to half of what I want, except that many apps and the keyboard do not do this, meaning I couldn't really type then.

Examples:
[image: Example of Nova Launcher][image: Example of Google Play Store]

Any ideas on what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem here. Are you using a OnePlus one by chance?

Comment: @Kakarot This is on an LG G2. I'm guessing it must just be a bug in the apps or something.

Comment: Restart your phone. It can solve the issue. Or, try clearing the **apps cache** and the **cache partition**.

Comment: Duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/184919/218526