# `adb shell wm overscan` makes apps leave blank spaces on top

Tags: adb, touchscreen

I've been following the instructions given [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115484/resize-screen-to-display-only-on-working-part-of-semi-functional-touchscreen/115652#115652). Basically I just ran:

```
adb shell wm overscan 0,320,0,0
```

to fix a broken touchscreen issue on my Sony Z3 Xperia Compact with Android 6.0.1

Now *some apps* (e.g. Play store, the default Xperia Launcher and Spotify) seem to now reserve additional space where they don't place things. To illustrate my point, I attach a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The black top third is what I wanted to have (because that's where the touchscreen doesn't respond). The middle third is what is added which I don't need. I'd rather use this space for the app I'm running, which is now entirely squeezed into the bottom third. As I said, this only applies to some apps.

*Edit 1* I found some apps where this sometimes happens and sometimes not. This seems to be related to whether or they are trying to show a menu bar on top.

*Edit 2* Gmail and google's Inbox have the same issue. Inbox even crashes.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/148993/218526