# After screen overscan resize, some apps double the resize

Tags: adb, screen, screen-resolution

The top section of my Samsung screen is completely non-responsive.

So I followed the excellent guide [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115484/resize-screen-to-display-only-on-working-part-of-semi-functional-touchscreen?newreg=9016552ca1fa42b8af141a5274d75f0b) to change the overscan.

I did `adb shell wm overscan 0,245,0,0`, followed by  `adb shell wm density 230` to normalize the display and not have words cut off.

It seemingly worked great, I can now access my notifications with swipe down, can interact with the controls that are almost always at the top of apps...

However, I'm wondering if there's some additional setting I need to change, because some of my apps are now adding a bunch of additional dead space and there's a lot of weirdness going on.

So for example, play store and instagram both add a bunch of additional "dead" space in the area that is actually alive, and they aren't even consistent between the two of them about how much they add.

[image: Image of play store and instagram apps side by side showing both having added whitespace of different sizes]

There's a lot of weird behavior going on around this. Nova launcher thinks 200 px of the active area don't exist, and therefore will not let me place widgets there, even though I can clearly move the widget with my finger and have it show up in the area. Maps displays the map up to an area that is one overscan displaced from the actual overscan, but then places the top bar an additional overscan down, which is just weird.

Not every app has this. Here's chrome, working normally, with just the overscan I set:

[image: chrome, with no added weird behaviors]

Edit: I see there's a similar question
[How to stop apps from doubling overscan?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148993/how-to-stop-apps-from-doubling-overscan). However, it has no answers, and the suggestion in the comments to clear cache partition and app cache does not help.